# Acento em ú tónico em segmentos -qúe- e -gúe-?

Tags: verbos, acordo-ortográfico, acentuação

Reparei que por vezes há discrepâncias em alguns acentos de verbos nas formas rizotónicas. Nos exemplos seguintes (3ª pessoa do singular do Conjuntivo Presente) no dicionário priberam as duas flexões têm acento no **"ú"**:

> [averig**ú**e](https://dicionario.priberam.org/Conjugar/averiguar)
>
> [adeq**ú**e](https://dicionario.priberam.org/Conjugar/adequar)

Enquanto se olharmos para as conjugações verbais no site conjugacao.com.br:

> [averigue](https://www.conjugacao.com.br/verbo-averiguar/)
>
> [ad**é**que](https://www.conjugacao.com.br/verbo-adequar/)

Vemos que *averiguar* não tem acento e em *adequar* o acento passa para o **"é"**. Há alguma regra ortográfica que tenha mudado para estas palavras? Acho o **"ú"** nos primeiros dois exemplos pouco habitual mas não sei explicar que regras regem a grafia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Adequar

Segundo o Houaiss online, os verbos terminados em -*equar*, -*iquar* e -*inquar* têm acento tônico no, mas admitem pronúncia com acento tônico no *u* sem diferença gráfica.

Mas. Segundo este artigo do Ciberdúvidas, o Houaiss também diz que há uma diferença entre Portugal e Brasil. No Brasil, usar-se-ia *adéque* e mais, mas admite-se *adeque* e mais. Em Portugal, usar-se-ia apenas *adeque* e mais.

O artigo do Ciberdúvidas é de 2008 e referencia uma versão física do Houaiss, de 2003, antes do acordo ortográfico entrar em vigor tanto no Brasil quanto em Portugal, segundo o [Portal da Língua](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php). A edição atual do [Houaiss online](https://houaiss.uol.com.br/), que não explicitou esta diferença, é de pelo menos 2012, já que sua introdução diz «Esta nova edição do Grande Dicionário Houaiss é fruto de onze anos de revisão e incorporação de novos dados ao primeiro conjunto de textos lançado em 2001». Ainda, ele contém referências ao *site* da Real Academia Española de 2014.

Eis o texto do Houaiss online:

> «-quar: adequar, alonginquar, [...]: são verbos que se grafam com -*quar* (em contraste com -cuar) para marcarem, latinamente, a ausência do hiato u-a (já que *qu* é orign. uma consoante gutural surda com prolongamento bilabial) e, decorrentemente, numa conjugação regular, conjugar-se-iam, p.ex., como oblíquo, oblíquas, oblíqua, obliquamos, obliquais, oblíquam; obliquava etc.; obliquei etc.; obliquarei etc.; obliquaria etc.; oblíque etc.; obliquasse etc.; obliquar etc.; obliquando; obliquado; modernamente, porém, admite-se para estes verbos terminados em -equar, -iquar e -inquar a acentuação (não gráfica) no -u-: obliquo, obliquas, obliqua etc.» — [Houaiss](https://houaiss.uol.com.br/corporativo/apps/uol_www/v6-1/html/index.php#3), verbete *-uar em **4)**.

### Averiguar

Segundo este outro [artigo](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/averigue-averificar-verificar/528) do Ciberdúvidas, o correto é apenas *averigua* (antigamente *averigúa*), sendo errado *averígua*. Mas o artigo é de 1997, também antes de o acordo ortográfico vigorar no Brasil e em Portugal. A maioria dos outros *sites* que vi dizem o que diz o Houaiss online (mais adiante).

Segundo o Houaiss online, os verbos terminados em -*guar* são mais complicados. Alguns admitem das acentuações e outros não. O verbo *averiguar* admite, tanto *averígue* quanto *averigue*.

> -guar: são v. que se grafam com -guar (em contraste com -goar) para marcarem a ausência do hiato u-a (já que gu é orign. em lat. uma consoante gutural sonora com prolongamento bilabial); os v. aguar, desaguar, enxaguar, aminguar, minguar, deslinguar, fraguar, oferecem, contudo, dois paradigmas quanto à acentuação nas formas rizotônicas: águo/aguo, águes/agues, águe/ague; mínguo/minguo, mínguas/minguas, míngua/mingua, minguamos, minguais, mínguam; deslínguo/deslinguo, deslíngues/deslingues, deslíngue/deslingue, deslinguamos, deslinguais, deslinguam; atreguar e eguar têm o -u- tônico nas f. rizotônicas; para apaniguar, apaziguar, averiguar, biguar, contiguar, santiguar admite-se também que a tonicidade caia sobre o -i- ou o -u-, p.ex., apaníguo ou apaniguo, apazígue ou apazigue; averíguem ou averiguem» — Houaiss, verbete *-uar* em **5)**.

Comment: A explicação mais detalhada que eu tinha encontrado também foi esta do Houaiss que citas, e como tu dizes não é completamente claro... Quando diz no Houaiss : ", admite-se para estes verbos terminados em -equar, -iquar e -inquar a acentuação **(não gráfica)** no -u-:" a parte do "não gráfica" sugere poder ser silaba tónica mas sem diacritico. Vou marcar a resposta como aceite, mas convido mais contribuições de outros usuários que ajudem a esclarecer ainda um pouco mais a pergunta.